# Configure VPN connection in terminal

Tags: ssh, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to setup a VPN connection on a remote box, via ssh, to use my account on [IPVanish](http://www.ipvanish.com/), this is a guide to configure the connection using the GUI, which is not my case because I need to ssh into the box [Visual guide](https://www.ipvanish.com/visualguides/PPTP/Ubuntu/). Could anyone please help me doing this steps using only the terminal. PPTP guides only include installation and some useless information for my case [pptp](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/documentation.phtml)

Much appreciation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package vpnc. This is a Cisco-compatible VPN client with can be installed with

apt-get install vpnc

then you have to configure it /etc/vpnc/vpnc.conf with your IP Vanish Credentials:

Set the following information:

```
IPSec gateway <Host Server>
IPSec ID <Vpn Username>
IPSec secret <Vpn Password>
Xauth username <your system username>
```